# How to verify the installed build of dd-wrt on used router

Tags: router, security, dd-wrt

I recently acquired a used router on which a previous owner had installed dd-wrt (I acquired it via a non-technical friend who bought it off ebay, so I have no idea who did the install).

I'm concerned that the device could have been flashed with an image that contained backdoors or other malware.  Is there a way to verify the firmware directly off of the device?  To clarify, I'm not asking about whatever may have been done to the device *after* the device was flashed (since that seems a much broader question, and much harder to answer).  I'm only asking if there is a way to verify that the current firmware came from an image whose checksum I could then also verify.

Comment: Just flash the image again with one you trust.  Why verify something when you can just reset the device and flash it again?

Comment: Yeah, that's plan B.  If there is a way to verify, then I'd prefer that since the flashing process is so cumbersome and risky.

Comment: How exactly is it risky?  DD-WRT to DD-WRT is nearly fool-proof.  You don't indicate anything about the router.  The only way to be sure is to wipe the memory then apply the firmware again.

Comment: My understanding in the past has been that mistakes made during the flashing process could result in "bricking" the device.

Comment: You would have to pull the plug, while the flashing process was happening, to brick the device at this stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to item #2 of [Elements of the Web-GUI](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Web_Interface#Elements_of_the_Web-GUI) on the dd-wrt wiki, the firmware version is displayed in the upper-right corner of the page as a link.  Clicking that link opens a pop-up that shows the full revision number.

Comment: This is not exactly what I originally asked, but seems like it's about as close as I'm going to get.